# Remove Resource (e.g. conference room) from an Event using Google Calendar API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I'm looking to write an app that will use Google Calendar API's to remove a resource (e.g. a conference room) from an event, if it's discovered that the room does not end up being needed.  Obviously the call to the API will be with administrative permissions, but we won't have access to individual user accounts to remove the resource from the event / invite.

Does anyone know of any way to use Google Calendar API's to update / alter the resources that are assigned to a meeting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Rooms are added to events as attendees and a copy is created on their calendar. You will just need to find the right event and delete it from the room's calendar (using Calendar API). Administrative permissions should give you all the access you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove a Room from an event as the Room if you have the Room's authentication credentials. You use the Rooms credentials and the https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events/{eventId} endpoint on the Room's primary calendar. This will not delete the event from the organizer's calendar.

Note: Regardless of the sendNotifications flag, Google will send a notification to the organizer when room delete/removes itself from an event (i.e. each time the endpoint is called). There is no workaround. If the organizer has all notifications turned off then they will not see these emails but it's still sent.

Answer (score -2):

I think removing resources from an event can be done by using Google Apps [Calendar Resource API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/). This API allows admin of the domain to add resources that users in the domain will be able to schedule on their calendars.

To delete a calendar resource, send a DELETE request to a resource ID's feed URL.

DELETE https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/calendar/resource/2.0/{domain name}/{resourceId}

Comment: This is in fact not true. You should not be deleting the entire resource just to remove it from a single event.

Comment: @luc, Thanks for the information. I never realized that rooms are added to events as attendees. So, I thought we dont have nay option to delete  with calendar api.